# Windows 7 -- cannot join domain. Network ID grayed out

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, windows-7, domain

I am trying to join a new Windows 7 PC to my domain, however the Network ID box and radio button are both grayed out. I have verified Internet connectivity, and the DNS settings on the PC point to the DNS server. There are many other PCs on the domain, and I add new ones quite often. I've never experienced this issue before. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What Edition of Windows 7 is this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like you have a home version, you need pro or above to join a domain.

Comment: Is there no way to do this without upgrading?

Comment: No, by design that is what makes it 'Home'